# Phaser 3: Text displayed using TrueType (.ttf) font renders distorted/blurred

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I'm loading a `.ttf` file via CSS and definition of `font-face`.

However, in the game the text renders blurry.

This is what I tried first (the font name is `truetypetest`):

```
this.sampleText = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, 'Almost clear text', { fontFamily: 'truetypetest' });
```

This actually renders almost clearly:

[Almost clear text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNVGY.png)

There is still some sort of lighter 'shadow' if you look carefully. Setting the resolution arbitrarily high via the below gives what I want:

```
this.sampleText = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, 'Clear text', { fontFamily: 'truetypetest' }).setResolution(10);
```

This renders clearly:

[Clear text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NCXF.png)

However, I don't want to be setting resolution this way as it's expensive memory-wise.

Furthermore, if I avoid setting the resolution AND specify a specific `fontSize`, via:

```
this.sampleText = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, 'Blurry text', { fontFamily: 'truetypetest', fontSize: '20px' });
```

This renders as blurry text:

[Blurry text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIaI0.png)

I should mention that I'm rendering the text inside a container (`GameObjects.Container`). Also, and I suspect this is the key problem - I'm zooming the canvas using:

```
scale: {
        parent: 'game-canvas',
        zoom: 2,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    }
```

I can't avoid using the zoom at this stage as the art is based off of this requirement. I've also tried using Bitmap font with no luck.

So my question is how do I use my custom font in my game that can render clear text for a wide range of different `fontSize`?

Thanks!

UPDATE

I've tried all of the following but with no luck:

- Used Bitmap Fonts (including adding png font-sheets for different sizes
- Tried rex WebFont Loader plugin: https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/webfontloader/#test-string (loads font but still blurry)
- Used a normal font like Roboto from the Google Font API. So the problem is not isolated to my particular font style (pixel-style font)
- Tried following the method described here: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/text/custom-webfont (CSS injection and custom webfont loading)
- Tried multiples of font sizes
- Tried autoRound=true

I find it difficult to believe what I'm trying to do is not possible. Its only text being rendered within a container. I would have thought there's a way of ensuring a single font can be used across a general range of sizes within the game? Failing that, I wouldn't mind using a more exhaustive strategy (multiple different font files at different sizes) if that is needed. There MUST be a way of rendering crisp text within a game? :(

Comment: Have you tried using the WebFontLoader plugin? https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/webfontloader/

Comment: I think you can try out based on this example instead: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/text/custom-webfont (this approach works for me actually). So basically got to inject the CSS first, then load the web font script in the `preload()` function, and finally load the font in the `create()` function.

Comment: @VTChiew Thanks for the detailed instructions. I've now tried this and the font has loaded. However, the text is still blurry :(

Comment: @VTChiew To be clear, I've tried both methods. Both are able to load the font. But for both, the font appears blurry. Let me know if you want any more info - e.g. the whole game config object, the exact loading/setup calls etc.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work out, just to be sure, is the `pixelArt` option is set to true?

Comment: @VTChiew Yes, `pixelArt=true` in config. No worries, thank you for your help!

Comment: @SolMan I have some questions: On which OS/ browser is it app running(and should be running)? Which font are you using, just because with the _ttf_ I used it is not blurry ?